# Laravel isset with array value

Tags: php, laravel

I am having an issue - well because the value I am trying to pull from the DB does not exist yet.

Is there away that I check if its isset?
Is there any better way that I can get my value from the db to save on double code?

**Controller:**

```
    $siteSocialFacebook      = socialSettings::where('socialName','=','facebook')->get();
    $siteFacebook            = $siteSocialFacebook[0]['socialLink'];
```

**Blade:**

```
value="{{ old('facebook', @$siteFacebook)}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will only ever expect one result, use `first()` instead of `get()` and skip the array. You can pass it into the Blade template like this:

```
return view('blade', [
    'siteFacebook' => $siteSocialFacebook['socialLink'] ?: null,
]);
```

This will prevent any issues with undefined parameters.

Edit: I just realized you're treating models as arrays. You can do this too:

```
return view('blade', [
    'siteFacebook' => $siteSocialFacebook->socialLink,
]);
```

That handles it for you.